# Setting autoscroll in QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside, qtreewidget

I am using QTreeWidget with single column. QTreeWidgetItem has multiple childs in some situations. I am updating dynamically, data in every QTreeWidgetItem. Now when I am adding this data to particular child & I am expanding it. But I am unable to set scroll to that particular QTreeWidgetItem.

Is it possible?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [scrollToItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#scrollToItem). You can pass a [scroll-hint](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#ScrollHint-enum) as the second argument to control how the scrolling is done:

```
    treewidget.scrollToItem(item, QtGui.QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
```

Comment: It works. Great dude. Thanx again. I really don't know how to appreciate it.